# Codeigniter error : define() expects at least 2 parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got a strange error in Codeigniter error : define() expects at least 2 parameters in Line 1.

What is wrong with my code below

```
<?php if ( ! define('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
}
```

Comment: probably looking for `defined` not `define`

Comment: Did you read the manual? It says *exactly* what the error messages says, `define()` expects two parameters. The name of the constant and the value. You probably mean to use `defined()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your looking for the function: [defined()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php)

With [define()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) your defining  a constant!

With defined() your checking if a constant is defined!

So try this:

```
!defined('BASEPATH')
```

Comment: but later on in my view I got an error Message: Call to undefined function base_url()

Comment: @Alexwood What should i do now? This question was about constants! So i don't see the code where you get that error! I would recommend you to make a new question! (I hope that this problem from this question is solved?)

Comment: @Alexwood Your welcome! Have a nice day! (For the other problem try to debug or make a new question! Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Rizer, I solved the problem. It's because I didn't load the url helper:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it works:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```